# Create ECK Entity via Ajax

Tags: 8

I'm trying to create a ECK Entity Content programmatically. I know, because I've used it elsewhere, I have the right code for creating the Entity Content but in my current setup it is not working anymore.

What I have is the following:

.routing.yml

```
timetracking.ajax_check:
path: '/js/timetracking/ajax/{nid}'
defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\timetracking\Controller\TimeTrackingController::timetrackingAjaxCheck'
requirements:
    _csrf_token: 'TRUE'
```

TimeTrackingControlle.php

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\timetracking\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

/**
 * Controller routines for user routes.
 */
class TimeTrackingController extends ControllerBase {

  public function timetrackingAjaxCheck($nid) {
    $user = $this->currentUser();
    $timer = (int) $this->timeSpentConfig->get('time_spent_timer');
    /* @    -- Save One Test Entity */
    $test_entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('time_tracking')->create([
      'type' => 'time',
      'title' => 'test-2',
      'field_id' => 1,
    ]);
    $test_entity->save();
  }
}
```

.js

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.timetracking = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      // Fetch ajax callback url
      var callbackUrl = '/js/timetracking/ajax/10';

      function timetrackingSendTimer() {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'get',
          url: callbackUrl,
          dataType: 'json',
          data: 'js=1&timer=10'
        });
      }
      timetrackingSendTimer();
    }
  }
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

When I put the *Save One Test Entity* in a .module file it creates an Enitity but when I put it inside the controller it is not. The controller is running as expected when I am debugging it using `DPM` I get a nice output.

I'm wondering if it is possible to do this inside the Controller? And if not how can I use Ajax to create an ECK Entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your route you require CSRF token and your ajax call is missing the CSRF token.

Get a CSRF token from ur drupal site using url "/session/token" and send it with your Ajax request.

But is it wise to do it this way? i don't know.

For making ECK Entity with ajax Post i would use REST resource or make a custom REST resource with basic_auth or cookie authentication, that way you wont need a CSRF Token.

Comment: Thanks, I found information about doing this via REST resource but wasn't sure what the best method was and to be honest REST resource is totally new for me I have no clue where to start. That is why I stuck with this method. What is the down side of my method against using REST?

Comment: You can start here (https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/restful-web-services-api/custom-rest-resources).

You can just copy your code to the REST Resource in the GET function and you are done.

Benefits are REST can have multiple output types like JSON / XML, multiple authentication like basic_auth or cookie and you can enable / disable it from the REST UI + a permission would be generated for the REST so you can give that to a role that is allowed to use the REST Resource.

There are more benefits that i forget to mention here.